# Postscript/EPS Drawing rectangle around text

Tags: hyperlink, postscript, pdflatex, eps

I have following postscript code

```
1448 2069 /moveto 
(Comparator) {show newpath}
```

I would like to draw a rectangle around the text(Comparator) as I need to provide a hyperlink to redirect it to abbreviation page.But I am struggling to find the rest of the 2 coordinates. Would some one please advise.

Comment: Your code will not show the Comparator because it will leave a procedure on the stack that contains `show newpath`, I don't understand what you are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friends are

*string bool* **charpath**

**pathbbox** *llx lly urx ury*

from the Postscript language.

so do

```
1448 2069 moveto 
(Comparator) false charpath pathbbox newpath
```

will give you left-x, lower-y, right-x and upper-y on the stack. You can subtract/add some constant values to give a little space around the text and then calculate width and height instead of the right/upper values and do a `rectstroke`

**EDIT small working sample**

```
%!PS
/Helvetica findfont 20 scalefont setfont
20 dup moveto (Link on page1) show newpath
[ /Rect [ 20 dup moveto (Link on page1) false charpath pathbbox 
 2 add 4 1 roll 2 add 4 1 roll 2 sub 4 1 roll 2 sub 4 1 roll
 newpath ] /Page 2 /Color [.7 0 0] /Subtype /Link /ANN  pdfmark
showpage
20 dup moveto (Target on page2) show
showpage
```

The line `2 add 4 1 roll ...` adds 2 more margin at each side. You can omit the entire line.

Comment: I am very new to this PS :( and cant understand what you have explained.  I want the 2 coordinates so that i can send those arguments to Rect[ x1,y1,x2,y2] and will use pdfmark for the hyperlinking.

Comment: [ /Rect [ 1448 2069 ? ? ]
/Page 160
/Color [.7 0 0]
/Subtype /Link
/ANN pdfmark      #I am trying to find the ? According to your code If I use pathbox the data is stored in stack and how can i fetch those values?sorry i am new to PS so asking some basic questions.

Comment: Your are not by chance trying to manually work around [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220700/) without even knowing postscript? **Good luck!** Didn't you find any normal latex tooltip package and tried to somehow add a hyperlink in there, even by editing the pdf? A web search for " latex tooltip " surely gives several interesting results

Comment: Your guess is correct.If I have to use latex then I need to install limit less packages so stopped doing that. Also both hyperlink and tool tip cannot be provided at the same time. I am trying to achieve it via PS. I read through a cook book and understood how the commands are given and the sequence they are executed.They are using stringwidth command in PS to get the displacement but I donot know how to fetch those values.If I can fetch them I can use them in my rectangle .

Comment: I tried your code.It has some error so pdf is not generated.

Comment: right, I was wrong about the closing square bracket, that was too much, I've added a small sample in the answer that works here with ps2pdf (from ghostscript) and acrobat reader. The rectangle is easy to get using the charpath / pathbox operators. You can download the [ps language reference](https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) from adobe too to see the details of all operators

Comment: I just viewed it via Ghost Script viewer and I can see the rectangle around text. Thanks so much.I shall try to integrate similar thing to my script.

Comment: I am using GS viewer 5.0 and I can see the rectangle box around the text.

Comment: my integration did not work even after many different attempt .OK i think i need to read the manual to get the rest of the 2 coordinates.

Comment: Actually I get the postscript as input which has 1448 2069 /moveto 
(Comparator) {show newpath} already in it. I can only append anything at the end of postscript.So at the very end I tried to append your code and it didn't generate anything. If I just give some random coordinates  /Rect [1559 1754 1549 1800] and use pdf mark it generates the box but at different place.I think I need to get the right 2 coordinates ? But it seams to be very difficult.

Comment: I imagined that after I understood what you are about to do. However, that makes it a lot more difficult. (It would make sense to see what comes after `newpath}` ) Appending code at the end of the file will likely use a completely different graphics context/fonts/font sizes/transformation matrices, end up on another page (the last one or one beyond even) than where you want the link etc.pp.... which would bring us back to the suggestion to maybe do try to use a package that is already designed to do what we are expensively (though not uninteresting) trying to fiddle out low-level

Comment: Thanks for the response.After newpath command there are some 3 1 roll moveto 1 sub {rlineto} repeat stroke some closepath eofill commands then a new parameter etc...As you guessed if I do something at the end of ps file the coordinates are different I mean X axis seams to be correct but Y axis is shown very low. Yes I will try with some packages.The whole day I was trying to with different PS commands to some how make it work but couldn't.

Comment: Also I was successful drawing something around the text with currentpoint and rlineto commands... but with no hyperlink to it .Although to use pdfmark(to insert hyperlink) i need rectangle coordinates .

Comment: Ahh! Stefan. Thank you so much I just tried your code in a different way.i.e instead of doing 20 dup what I have done is used my move points and itworked like magic :) . I have tested this by adding the code in middle of PS file manually. Now I need to automate this using perl .Thanks again

Comment: Ouch, that surely was what I meant! Sorry for making an example with different text position ;-) Congratulations! - and good luck with perl!

Comment: No Donot say sorry ,I think I misunderstood that it is font :) . My Perl at the moment is not going good because my function is called under multi thread so when I am trying to open my PS file to write data it is writing some other data as well and corrupting my PS code :). Just viewing some file locking methods.Thank you

Comment: Good luck really! I'm sure that if you got this far now, you will be able to get it running!